# regarding extraction of value from grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Q:

**My aspx:**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    &nbsp;
    <h1>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        MANAGE ADS</h1>
    <br />
    <br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <p>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
            CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="postid" ForeColor="#333333" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowSelectButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="userid" HeaderText="userid" SortExpression="userid" ReadOnly="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="title" HeaderText="title" SortExpression="title" ReadOnly="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ad_description" HeaderText="ad_description" SortExpression="ad_description"
                    ReadOnly="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="status_post" HeaderText="status_post" SortExpression="status_post" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="postid" HeaderText="postid" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True"
                    SortExpression="postid" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="date_creation" HeaderText="date_creation" SortExpression="date_creation"
                    ReadOnly="True" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        </asp:GridView>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Do you want to Delete" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Visible="False">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="you have selected :"></asp:Label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Delete" Height="29px" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
        </asp:Panel>
        <p>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues"
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:eclassConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [postad] WHERE [postid] = @original_postid AND (([userid] = @original_userid) OR ([userid] IS NULL AND @original_userid IS NULL)) AND [title] = @original_title AND [ad_description] = @original_ad_description AND [status_post] = @original_status_post AND [date_creation] = @original_date_creation"
                InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [postad] ([userid], [title], [ad_description], [status_post], [date_creation]) VALUES (@userid, @title, @ad_description, @status_post, @date_creation)"
                OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting1"
                SelectCommand="SELECT [userid], [title], [ad_description], [status_post], [postid], [date_creation] FROM [postad]"
                UpdateCommand="UPDATE [postad] SET [status_post] = @status_post WHERE [status_post] = @original_status_post and [postid]=@original_postid">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="original_postid" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="original_userid" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="original_title" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="original_ad_description" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="original_status_post" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="original_date_creation" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="userid" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="title" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="ad_description" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="status_post" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter DbType="DateTime" Name="date_creation" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="original_postid" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="original_userid" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="original_title" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="original_ad_description" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="original_status_post" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter DbType="DateTime" Name="original_date_creation" />
                </UpdateParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="userid" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="title" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="ad_description" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="status_post" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter DbType="DateTime" Name="date_creation" />
                </InsertParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

**and my .cs code :**

```
public partial class adminMaintainUserAds : System.Web.UI.Page

{
    int id = 0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting1(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel1.Visible = true;
        Label2.Text = id.ToString();
        Label2.Visible = true;
    }
    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow r = GridView1.SelectedRow;
     getting error here...  id =Convert.toint32Int32(r.Cells[4].Text);
       // int id1 = Convert.ToInt32(id);
        //Session["grid"] = id1;
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string query = "update postad set status_post=@del where postid=@post";
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DELL-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=eclass;Persist Security Info=True;integrated security = true");
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand q1 = new SqlCommand(query,myConnection);
        q1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@del", "delete");
        q1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@post",id);
        try
        {

            int i = Convert.ToInt32(q1.ExecuteNonQuery());
            if (i > 0)
            {
                Panel1.Visible = false;
                Label3.Text = "Deleted";
                Label3.Visible = true;

                myConnection.Close();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ae)
        {
            Label3.Text = "Error";
        }

    }
}
```

**How to extract the value from the `gridview` and use it as integer as i have to do checking based on this value in data base.?**

Comment: please post what is the error exactly

Answer (score 0):

```
   protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);//Get the index

                if (e.CommandName == "Select_ad")
                {

                  int id =int.Parse(GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[4].Text);   
                  //your code

                }
            }


            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                string message = ee.Message;
            }
        }
```

Note:1- in aspx :

```
CommandArgument='<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex%>' CommandName = "Select_ad"
```

for the `button` in the gridview.

**you don't need to copy all your code.**